# GET or POST request if I'm getting an image from a database but it increments a counter?

Tags: javascript, http, post, get

I have an HTTP request that retrieves an image from a database. When image retrieval happens, a view counter is incremented by one. Should this HTTP request be a GET request, or a POST request (given some state is modified by the request)?

Thanks!

Comment: The main purpose of the request is to **get** the image so I'd go with GET.

Comment: `GET` or `POST` is determined yourself or by your api design. if you follow the restful api design, then it should be `GET`. Seems that you are getting a image from server. reference: https://medium.com/edureka/what-is-rest-api-d26ea9000ee6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the significance of incrementing the counter.

If increasing the counter is the point (or one of the points since you are also retrieving an image) of the request, then POST makes sense.

It is fine to use GET for retrieving data when there are changes on the server which are *side effects* (such as logging).

The working in [the spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1) says:

> Request methods are considered "safe" if their defined semantics are    essentially read-only; i.e., the client does not request, and does    not expect, any state change on the origin server as a result of    applying a safe method to a target resource.  Likewise, reasonable    use of a safe method is not expected to cause any harm, loss of    property, or unusual burden on the origin server.
>
> This definition of safe methods does not prevent an implementation from including behavior that is potentially harmful, that is not entirely read-only, or that causes side effects while invoking a safe method.  **What is important, however, is that the client did not request that additional behavior and cannot be held accountable for  it.  For example, most servers append request information to access log files at the completion of every response, regardless of the method, and that is considered safe even though the log storage might become full and crash the server.  Likewise, a safe request initiated by selecting an advertisement on the Web will often have the side  effect of charging an advertising account.**

Comment: Thanks for the response! The counter is not significant, so sounds like it should be a get. Follow-up question - what if my server is generating an image based on inputted text from the client? It should still be a post then right? Asking because I see similar APIs that have this request as a post, and wondering if they just aren't being RESTful.

Comment: Sounds like the client is just asking for an image (even if the image has to be created on the fly). It isn't asking to publish new content for other people or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

You should dont have two routes. You only need one route.

In this route, you increment the counter on end of req before returns the image.

But... are you returning the base64 image?
If you are returning base64 image, consider returns the image link.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).